# Python: Formatting columns with mixed string and date values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**My table:**

| ID | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2022-11-14 00:00:00 | 2023-05-11 00:00:00 |
| 02 | 2022-11-14 00:00:00 | TBD |
| 03 | TBD | TBD |
| 04 | - | - |

**The issue:**

I would like to change the date format to `'%d.%m.%Y'` while keeping the string values.
Is there an efficient solution to this issue?

*Dates are currently in `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` by default

**My attempt for one column:**

```
df['Start Date'] = df['Start Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='ignore'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) on the date columns, then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with the original data and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) the DataFrame:

```
df.update(
 df.filter(like='Date')
   .apply(lambda s: pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'))
   .fillna(df)
)
```

updated `df`:

```
   ID  Start Date    End Date
0   1  14.11.2022  11.05.2023
1   2  14.11.2022         TBD
2   3         TBD         TBD
3   4           -           -
```

Comment: @Bloom I selected the columns based on the presence of `Date` in it, what is your real pattern? You can use `df[list_of_cols_to_update]` in place of `df.filter(like='Date')`